# If line contains word, put line into variable

Tags: ruby

I spent a few hours googling, but couldn't find an exact answer.

I want to search through a multi-line text file, and if a line contains `'dog'`, put that line into a variable.

Here's the code I have:

```
if File.foreach('textfile.txt').grep(/dog/)
```

I would like the next line of code to put the line containing `'dog'` into the variable `wordline`.

I also might search for several terms instead of just one, i.e.:

```
if File.foreach('textfile.txt').grep(/cat|dog/)
```

I realize it might also be done in a different way, something like:

```
wordline=File.foreach('textile.txt').grep(/dog/)
```

but I don't know the syntax for that inline version.

Edit: this is my first post ever and I'm a total Ruby newb.. which I mentioned in my post. But someone edited all that out and down voted my post. I did read the FAQ before posting, so an explanation of censorious actions would be welcome next time.

Comment: As a note `grep` always returns an array, and arrays, even empty, are always logically true. That `if` will never not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea here would be:

```
matching = File.readlines('text.txt').grep(/dog|cat/)
```

Or more generally:

```
terms = %w[ dog cat ]

matching = File.readlines('text.txt').grep(Regexp.union(terms))
```

Since `matching` is an array you can reference elements in it like `matching[0]` or `matching.first` or iterate over it when necessary with `.each`. To assign the first match to a variable:

```
first_match = matching.first
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the syntax I wanted. My test worked and I got the line containing the requested word. However, it seems this file's lines have \t at the beginning. And sometimes \n at the end.
Is there a way to remove those \t\n characters with the same one-line syntax? i.e. so that it would function like: 

matching = File.readlines('text.txt').grep(/dog|cat/)remove '\n' and '\t'

Or maybe I'll just have to make a 2nd variable from 'matching,' with the tabs and newlines stripped

Comment: You can remove newlines like `File.readlines(...).map { |s| s.gsub(/\s+/, '') }` to strip any spaces, tabs or newlines out. You can also keep chaining off of that as necessary.

Comment: That makes the line unreadable though with spaces between words gone. Could I use .map { |s| s.gsub(/\t\n/, ' ') } to just take out newlines and tabs?

Comment: In that case `/[\t\n]/` does it. That means "any of" using the `[...]` notation. `\t\n` otherwise means "tab followed by newline".